# Delete numbers, special characters and text containing special characters in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have few text files from which :

> I need to delete all numbers(0 to 9), 
>   special characters(they are "{" and "[")
>   and all the words containing a "#"
>   ( for eg, good#boy, very#good#boy a#very#good#boy)

How can I do this with Notepad++?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of regular expressions it's easy. Go to `Search` > `Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   [0-9\{\}\[\]]|[a-zA-Z]+\#[a-zA-Z\#]+
   ```
2. Replace with:

   ```
   [leave empty!]
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press "Replace All"

You can test it at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/aH9yZ6).